# Notes should be showed only for the author

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In my note taking project, I want to do so, that notes should be showed only for the author of the object. I am trying to solve this problem for 3 days. But, I could not solve this. Please Help! Thanks in an advance

**view.py**

```
 @login_required(login_url='login')
def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            obj.owner = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('/')

    form =  TaskForm()
    user = request
    context = {
    'tasks' : tasks,
    'form':form,
    'obj':obj
    
    }
    return render(request, 'list.html',context)
```

***models.py***

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Task` will need a `ForeignKey` to the user model, to keep track who created the task, so:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I think in that case it is better to recreate the migration file that creates the table for the `Task` model.

Now that we have an owner of the `Task`s, we can filter with:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.owner = request.user
            obj = form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form =  TaskForm()
    context = {
        'tasks' : tasks,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```